# Why is DbFunctions.Right method not working in sorting?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort strings containing numbers using the following function:

```
var products = _dbContext.Products
                .Include(x => x.Category) 
                .OrderBy(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Right("00000" + x.ProductId, 7))
                .AsNoTracking();
```

ut I am getting such an error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>().OrderBy(b => DbFunctions.Right(stringArgument: "00000" + b.ProductId, length: (long?)7))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method'System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Right' failed.`

I also used the `PadLeft()` function but it doesn't work either

Comment: Because you are using EF Core? =)

Comment: Are you sure that `x.ProductId` has 2 digits or more?

Comment: @BehnamIzadi Yes

Comment: @GuruStron There is an equivalent of such a method in EF Core?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: For EF Core 6.0, you can use `String.Substring()`: `("00000"+b.ProductId).Substring(b.ProductId.Length-2)` (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions)

Comment: @NetMage It's LINQ To Entities, EF Core 6.x

Comment: And the database provider?

Comment: SQL Server provider